# Systemd not setting RUNTIME_DIRECTORY env when it should?

Tags: environment-variables, systemd

I have a pretty simple test service.
Ultimately I'll be running a `node` daemon, but debugging this problem with `env` for now...

```
$ systemctl cat http-endpoints
# /etc/systemd/system/http-endpoints.service
[Unit]
Description=HTTP endpoints for triggering events
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
;PassEnvironment=RUNTIME_DIRECTORY
RuntimeDirectory=endpoints
Environment=TEST=asdf
ExecStart=/usr/bin/env

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I'm trying to use the `RuntimeDirectory=` feature of systemd.
I am expecting the environment variable `RUNTIME_DIRECTORY`.

It is not getting set.

```
systemd[1]: Started HTTP endpoints for triggering events.
env[26794]: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
env[26794]: PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
env[26794]: INVOCATION_ID=fb24db240f454722b847ab7cefd5eb59
env[26794]: JOURNAL_STREAM=9:8063338
env[26794]: TEST=asdf
```

I have tried a few things.

If I manually set it, `Environment=RUNTIME_DIRECTORY=/run/endpoints`, it works.
But that config should not be necessary.

The `/run/endpoints` directory is created as expected (and promptly deleted because `env` exits, but that's not the problem).

```
$ systemd --version
systemd 237
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid
```

Comment: Maybe this would be more appropriate for superuser (if for a personal setup) or serverfault (if for a “corporate/business/professional” one)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu 18.04.3 does not have the lastest systemd.

The support for the environment variables was added in v240.

> ```
> CHANGES WITH 240:
>     * When the RuntimeDirectory=, StateDirectory=, CacheDirectory=,
>       LogsDirectory=, ConfigurationDirectory= settings are used in a
>       service the executed processes will now receive a set of environment
>       variables containing the full paths of these directories.
>       Specifically, RUNTIME_DIRECTORY=, STATE_DIRECTORY, CACHE_DIRECTORY,
>       LOGS_DIRECTORY, CONFIGURATION_DIRECTORY are now set if these options
>       are used. Note that these options may be used multiple times per
>       service in which case the resulting paths will be concatenated and
>       separated by colons.
> ```

I hope this saves someone the time I spent trying to figure this out.